# Twitter Bootstrap, form wrapping a table causes table to mis-align

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This is mostly a CSS/HTML problem, one which is driving me a little bit mad, and shouldn't be so complicated...

I'm using twitter bootstrap 3 for my CSS, and doing the development on a local LAMP stack which is fully updated, mostly viewing in Firefox for now.

I have a form wrapping a table (spare me the wrath for using tables, I'm mostly focused on the PHP and don't care to research better formatting with CSS right now **unless of course you think it will 100% solve this problem**) which is dynamically filled with results from PHP based on a mysql query using a 'while' loop. The form has text inputs and select drop-downs giving users the ability to update/delete information or users from a database, each in its own cell. The rows are created in the 'while' loop, but the form and table are started and ended outside the loop (obviously). The submit button is also loaded after the loop, so it either ends up in it's own cell, or outside of the table also.

All of it is loaded via Ajax into a div on a main page. The first page included below is a search form, with a div at the bottom called 'results'. The table/forms are supposed to load in 'results', but instead load OUTSIDE the entire 'container' div which is set several levels up, and contains everything.

The next page is the form itself, and includes a div at the bottom called 'answer' which simply show messages from the form processing script. (success, failure, errors, etc.)

I'm guessing this has to do with the classes set up in the bootstrap.css file, possibly relating to display: inline vs block? I've tried adding a class in my custom css file which sets forms to display inline, and wrapping the form around the table, but to no avail. HTML/CSS is not exactly my strong suit, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**FULL HTML of relevant pages**

Please note because this is contained in a PHP file, there is no html, head, or body tag, as those are all created several layers up.

**Search page, which gets results from the DB, formatted in the table below**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#results").load('edit.forms.php', function (){
            });
        });

        $("#search").submit(function(){

          $.ajax({
                url: 'forms.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#search").serialize(),         
                success: function(data) {
                $("#results").empty();
                $("#results").append(data);
                }
            });
            return false;       
        });

      </script>

    <div class='col-md-4'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <h3>Search for users to edit:</h3> 
            <form method='POST' action='' id='search'>
            <input type='text' name='search' value='$search' />
            <input type='submit' value='Search' />
            <br /><p><i>(Optional)</i>Number of results to show:
            <select name='num' size='1'>
                <option value='5'>5</option>
                <option value='10'>10</option>
                <option value='15'>15</option>
                <option value='all'>All</option>
            </select></p>
            </form>
        <p>You can search by <i>name, family, class, committee, 
        phone number,</i> etc..</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'></div>        

    <div class='row memdb' id='results'></div>
```

**Page with the forms, and the alignment issue**

```
<script>

$("#editUsers").submit(function(){

$.ajax({
url: 'file.php',
type: 'POST',
data: $("#editUsers").serialize(),
success: function(data) {
$("#answer").empty();
$("#answer").append(data);
}
});
return false;
});     
</script>

<form method='POST' action='' id='editUsers'>
<table>                 
 <tr>            
    <th class='col-sm-2'>Name</th>
    <th class='col-sm-1'>Family</th>
    <th class='col-sm-2'>Position</th>
    <th class='col-sm-2'>Committees</th>
    <th class='col-sm-1'>Class</th>
    <th class='col-sm-2'>Phone</th>
    <th class='col-sm-1'>Email</th>
    <th class='col-sm-1'>Status</th>
 </tr>

A WHILE loop in the PHP file fills in all of the cells with form elements.
Each cell is formatted fine in the loop, and it ends with </td></tr>, then
when the loop is done, it echoes this:

</table>                
<hr class='small-divider'></hr>
<input type='submit' value='Update Records' />
</form>
```

[Screen shot](http://imgur.com/Qe4y8jH)

In the above screen shot, obviously the forms should be in the div under the search box.

Comment: hi, you should not cross html tags, because it can make any strange behaviour in css. TB is a tool and you can always correct/extend them for your case. Your question is long so example would be helpful.

Comment: Cross HTML tags? You mean by starting/ending the form outside the table, even though there are form elements in the table? Making the form completely contained in the table causes the same issue...

Comment: and you can post anywhere your html file for read? I want to see what your code does

Comment: Sorry, the post should be much better/make more sense now. I should have included the full code to begin with.

Comment: ty for code but you can post any screenshots? The code looks fine. I can look at your code in browser? You can post only generated html page?

Comment: and better solution is show/hide form on page instead of return him via ajax. Better approach is to use only data request via ajax then html blocks

Comment: from screenshot you try <div style="clear:both"></div> under the search div. If not help you, copy paste your html dump into fiddle i look at that for solution

Comment: THANK YOU! That fixed it!

What does setting style="clear:both" do? Clear the contents of the divs?

Thank you again for your patience and help! If you want to write that as an answer, I will mark it answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clear reset your floating elements. If you use BT floating elements i recommend to you after each row reset floating e.g.

```
<div class='col-md-4'></div>
<div class='col-md-4'></div>
<div class='col-md-4'></div>
<div style='clear:both'></div> // reset to next row
<div class='col-md-4'></div>
<div class='col-md-4'></div>
<div class='col-md-4'></div>
```

> both - No floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side

[W3C clear reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

man, css is a magic =)

Comment: that is pretty awesome! thanks again, that really helped me not lose my mind!